# Why doesnt a java program proceed to do actions when the window is switched?

Tags: java

Im working on an Java program, in which a new external program is opened then the mouse gets moved to a position and then some keyboard actions are executed. I execute all those actions with a Robot but I noticed, that the Actions wont work after the external program gets opened. Do you have a clue how to fix this?

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(400, 50);
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder("PATH/TO/PROGRAM.exe").start();
            copy(TEXT Which IS COPIED TO CLIPBOARD);
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN);
```

copy() is a method which copies a String into the clipboard

Comment: Any code to share?

Comment: Which OS you are running on?

Comment: Windows 10 is my os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that **Frame Focus** is changed once you've executed the PROGRAM.exe,So actions will not effect the program.
You need to gain focus to PROGRAM.exe frame before creating any actions on it.

Try the following:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(400, 50);
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("PATH/TO/PROGRAM.exe").start();
//Gaining Focus using Alt+Tab Keys
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.delay(10);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
// Continuing the rest of program
Thread.sleep(7000);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN);
```